# If I create a Live usb bootable distro with persistence files, can I later use the usb to install to the hard drive?

Tags: installation, sound, cd, offline, persistence

I need to know if i create a Live usb bootable distro with persistence files, can i later use the usb to install the distro to the hard drive?

If so will the persistence files install the distro in the like manner in which i have adjusted settings and downloaded extra packages that the distro didn't have to begin with?

I searched and searched about this topic with google but i don't see the answer anywhere.

If the installation to hard drive with persistence files is ok, is it a safe practice?

I ask this because i have an old hp 533w with about 1G RAM and a 60 G hard drive.The modem is how you go online with it, so i need a preconfigured linux os to be able to use the setup without going online.

Also does any distro automatically carry the codecs for sound and being able to use audio editors and drivers for cd rom drives.

This question would help a lot of people trying to switch over from the panes(pains) OS onto any type of computer without internet access.

Thank you and may God bless your day!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have asked three questions. Please edit the question and ask only one question at a time. Read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). With 1GB RAM consider installing [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). Search for how to update (L)Ubuntu without Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence files stays on the usb. the new install done from the usb is going to be a fresh install. There is not an easy click a button way to install the presisted files to the new installed computer.

I would suggest just run the computer using the usb as your primary drive and use the internal hdd for storage.